# jasmine mockDate always one month off

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

I'm trying to use jasmine's `mockDate()` to write a time-relative unit test:

```
it("cookie_expiration() is 30 days out", function () {
    var baseTime = new Date(2016, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);
    console.info( new Date() );
    ...
});
```

I think this is exactly what they show in [the documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction) but what I see in the console is: `Tue Nov 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

```
"devDependencies": {
  "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
  "karma": "^1.5.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
  "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Date | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date),

> note that the month is 0-based

So, it's not an issue with `jasmine`'s `mockDate`. It's the native `Date`.

Here's the snippet showing it's November :)

```js
var baseTime = new Date(2016, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

console.log("BaseTime month is " + monthNames[baseTime.getMonth()]);
```